# Prove an inequality with Jensen's inequality and its companion

Tags: fake-proofs, karamata-inequality

Problem :

Let $f(x)$ be continuous convex  increasing on $(0,\infty)$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$ ; $x,a,\alpha>0$ with the constraint :

$$\infty>\alpha\geq x\geq \frac{xf'\left(x\right)+af'\left(a\right)}{f'\left(x\right)+f'\left(a\right)}\geq \frac{\left(x+a\right)}{2}\geq a $$

Where $\forall n\ge 2$ :$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ix^i$$ And $a_0 \ge a_1 \ge ... \ge a_n>0$

Then we have for $a,x,\alpha$ sufficiently large :

$$f\left(\frac{\left(x+a\right)}{2}\right)+f\left(\frac{\left(xf'\left(x\right)+af'\left(a\right)\right)}{f'\left(x\right)+f'\left(a\right)}\right)-f\left(a\right)-f\left(x\right)+f(\alpha)\geq f(\alpha)$$

---

---

My attempt :

We use majorization (with an alternative criteria see Aops page) as first step:

$$\alpha=\alpha$$

And :

$$\alpha+x\geq \alpha+\frac{xf'\left(x\right)+af'\left(a\right)}{f'\left(x\right)+f'\left(a\right)}$$

Finally :
$$\frac{x+a}{2}+\frac{xf'\left(x\right)+af'\left(a\right)}{f'\left(x\right)+f'\left(a\right)}-a-x\leq 0$$

Wich is wrong .

---

---

How to prove it ?

Comment: The idea of the power series is mine but the decreasing order is due to $p4sch$ (Thanks you)

Comment: Starting from the definition of $f(x)$ we have the lower bound : $$f(x)\geq xf'\left(0\right)+\frac{f''\left(0\right)}{2}\left(x^{2}\right)+\frac{f'''\left(0\right)}{6}x^{3}+\cdots+\frac{f^{\left(n-1\right)}\left(0\right)}{\left(n-1\right)!}x^{n-1}$$ For an upper bound see the divided difference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences

Answer (score 1):

I take a simple example :

Let $x>0$ such that $f(x)=x+kx^2$ with $0<k<1$ and $a=0$ , $b>0$ :

Then it seems we have the equality :

$$f\left(\frac{\left(x+a\right)}{2}\right)+f\left(\frac{\left(xf'\left(x\right)+af'\left(a\right)\right)}{f'\left(x\right)+f'\left(a\right)}\right)-f\left(a\right)-f\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(f\left(a\right)-f\left(b\right)\right)}{a-b}\left(\frac{\left(x-a\right)}{2}\right)+f\left(a\right)-f'\left(x\right)\left(x-\frac{\left(xf'\left(x\right)+af'\left(a\right)\right)}{f'\left(x\right)+f'\left(a\right)}\right)+\frac{f''\left(x\right)}{2}\left(\left(x-\frac{\left(xf'\left(x\right)+af'\left(a\right)\right)}{f'\left(x\right)+f'\left(a\right)}\right)\right)^{2}$$

For $x=2b$

Perhaps we can generalize this example but it seems really hard .

Edit 27/06/2022 :

We have a simple generalization via this example :

Let $m=2,a=k=0.5,b=0.9,x\geq 1/8$

Now and very simply we add an $x$ on :

$$r\left(x\right)=x\left(f\left(\frac{a+x}{2}\right)+f\left(\frac{\left(xf'\left(x\right)+af'\left(a\right)\right)}{f'\left(x\right)+f'\left(a\right)}\right)-f\left(x\right)-f\left(a\right)\right)$$

Where :

$$f(x)=\left(2+x+kx^{2}\right)$$

And now for $m=2,a=k=0.5,b=0.9,x\geq 1/8$ it seems we have the inequality :

$$r(x)\leq p\left(x\right)=g\left(\frac{a+x}{2}\right)+g\left(\frac{\left(xg'\left(x\right)+ag'\left(a\right)\right)}{g'\left(x\right)+g'\left(a\right)}\right)-g\left(x\right)-g\left(a\right)$$

Where $g\left(x\right)=x\left(m+x+kx^{2}\right)$